# Raising salary by 15% using SQL only?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to modify the `SCOTT` schema by raising employees salaries by 15%. If the resulting salary exceeds his or her highest possible salary, `HISAL`, in `SALGRADE` we just use `HISAL`, my code is:

```
select 
  coalesce((
    select   sal*1.15 
    from emp , salgrade  
    where 
      sal*1.15<=hisal
   ) , 
   (select hisal from emp ,salgrade where sal*1.15>hisal )) raised_sal
from emp ;
```

The inner select returns multiple rows

Does anyone have suggestions or different code?

Answer (score 3):

If we break-down what you're trying to do:

`coalesce` gives the first value, unless that is null then the second etc. You haven't specified any join condition, so you're doing a [`cartesian join`](http://orafaq.com/wiki/Cartesian_join) between `emp` and `salgrade`. This will return the number of rows in `emp` **multiplied by** the number of rows in `salgrade`; subject to your join condition.

The second part of your query does exactly the same in the opposite direction.

Assuming a table_structure of:

```
create table emp (
        emp_id number
      , salary number -- current salary
      , salgrade_id number -- current salary grade 
      , dept_id -- current department
         );

create table salgrade (
      , salgrade_id number
      , hisal number -- max salary for that grade
       );
```

You want to be doing something like this:

```
select least( e.salary * 1.15, s.hisal )
  from emp e
  join salgrade s
    on e.salgrade_id = s.salgrade_id
```

The [`least` function](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/least.php) is similar to `min`; in that it will take the minimum value. However, it works over multiple columns on the same row, rather than multiple rows over the same column.

By taking the `least` of `hisal` and `salary * 1.15` we ensure that if the salary increase is higher than `hisal` then `hisal` is taken instead.

In this case `join` means that for every `emp_id` we're taking the `hisal` for the appropriate salary grade. I would highly recommend [reading up on SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) - this link was 7th on Google, which was a bit of a surprise ( Jeff seems to be everywhere ), but it's quite good and has many more links.

To change the query to enable you to do it for all employees earning over 100,000 ( the rich get richer ) it would look something like this:

```
select least( e.salary * 1.15, s.hisal )
  from emp e
  join salgrade s
    on e.salgrade_id = s.salgrade_id
 where e.salary > 100000
```

Or to complicate matters if you wanted to do it for only IT peoples ( why not ), you could extend it to something like this:

```
select least( e.salary * 1.15, s.hisal )
  from emp e
  join salgrade s
    on e.salgrade_id = s.salgrade_id
  join dept d
    on e.dept_id = d.dept_id
 where d.dept = 'IT'
```

These joins by being `inner joins` as opposed to `outer joins` ( normally `left outer joins` - see the link ) imply that every employee has a grade and a department.

Comment: Ben, salgrade_id don't exists.

Comment: @danihp, not having or being able to find out a schema I had to improvise. There must be a unique identifier in `salgrade` with a foreign key using this identifier in `emp` otherwise the schema is, essentially, useless; substitute this identifier for `salgrade_id`

Comment: The major issue is to know how to join `emp` with `salgrade` through non equijoin. THe schema is not useless without this foreigh key.

Comment: @danihp, it's a fair point. "Useless" is a very strong word; but it's still well designed.

Comment: Is only for academic purposes.

Comment: thank you for this great explanation , i have also write these codes that may be helpful

Answer (score 1):

You should join emp with salgrade through a **non equijoin**:

```
    select   sal*1.15 
    from 
      emp 
        inner join
      salgrade sg
        on emp.sal BETWEEN sg.losal AND sg.hisal  <-- here!
    where 
      sal*1.15<=hisal
```

More info: [Introduction to Basic SQL, Part 3 - Complex Joins and Sub-queries](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/oracle-guide/introduction-to-basic-sql-part-3-complex-joins-and-subqueries-9785):

> "we joined using the BETWEEN operator. The paybands in the SALGRADE
>   table use a range of salary to designate a grade."

**EDIT**

To calculate the employee grade you should look for employee salary and look into salgrade for a salary range that contains employee salary.

This is the salgrade data:

```
...
INSERT INTO SALGRADE VALUES (2,1201,1400);
INSERT INTO SALGRADE VALUES (3,1401,2000);
...
```

If employee salary is 1495 that means that his grade is 2.

If you increase 1395 in 15% then this is out of range of your salrange and, as you explain, you should set salary at 1400 that is the hisal for range 2.

Your query:

```
select 
  coalesce((
    select   sal*1.15 
    from emp e2
    inner join
       salgrade sg
            on e2.sal BETWEEN sg.losal AND sg.hisal
    where 
      e2.EMPNO = e1.EMPNO and
      sal*1.15<=hisal
   ) , 
   (select hisal from emp e2 inner join salgrade sg
    on e2.sal BETWEEN sg.losal AND sg.hisal
    where e2.EMPNO = e1.EMPNO 
   )) raised_sal
from emp e1 ;
```

Without subqueries:

```
select 
   case 
     when sal*1.15  < hisal then sal*1.15 
     when sal*1.15  >= hisal then hisal
   end
   raised_sal
from 
   emp e1 
     inner join
   salgrade sg
     on e1.sal BETWEEN sg.losal AND sg.hisal
```

Disclaimer, not tested.

Comment: but danihp it will not give hisal value when employee has salary value greater then hisal?

employee having this kind of case will not be a part of this output .. Right ?

Comment: Denihp I think I didn't describe properly that time ... What I wanna to say that 'e1.sal between sg.losal AND sg.hisal' this condition should not be there to satisfy the second condition of this 'when case ' sentence .. 

please think again .. you will surely get my point.. 

by the way your way of query is very good ..

Comment: are you talking about employees that has salary * 1.15 greater than greatest hisal? I think that this is not a special case, is a regular case, will not be a part of output

Comment: thank you all i wrote also these codes --using union
select ename , sal , sal*1.15 from emp , salgrade where   sal between losal and hisal and  emp.sal*1.15<=salgrade.hisal
union
select ename , sal , sal*1.15 from emp , salgrade where   sal between losal and hisal and  emp.sal*1.15>salgrade.hisa
--using case
select ename , sal, ( case when sal*1.15<=hisal then sal*1.15 when sal*1.15>hisal then hisal end ) new_sal
from emp , salgrade
where sal between losal and hisal ;

Comment: --more simple case

select ename , sal,  case when sal*1.15<=hisal then sal*1.15
                          else hisal
                           end as new_sal
from emp , salgrade
where sal between losal and hisal ;

--using decode

select ename , sal,  decode ( trunc(sal*1.15/hisal) , 1,hisal
                                                    ,0,sal*1.15) new_sal
                                       
from emp , salgrade
where sal between losal and hisal ;

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed only join condition ...

in both the query you can give join condition, if any (like emp.employee_name = salgrade.employee_name)

and have to give inner query condition also...
like

```
select 
  coalesce((
    select   sal*1.15 
    from emp e2, salgrade  
    where 
      sal*1.15<=hisal
and e2.employee_name = e1.employee_name
   ) , 
   (select hisal from emp e3,salgrade where sal*1.15>hisal 
and e3.employee_name = e1.emplyee_name
)) raised_sal
from emp e1;
```

Comment: Joining on name is a way to make very large mistakes, you need to use a unique identifier and name is not guaranteed to be unique. I got bored of counting the number of Pratik Garg's registered with Facebook when I found 38.

Comment: that was just hint not a proper query .. 

what I was telling that you are getting multiple rows exception just because of absence of the sub query conditions .. 

if you will add these conditions then you will get single row (most probably,.... if you don't have multiple records for a customer in your table .. )